# How do I append data to a jquery-ujs post request in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have an Ajax form with a `data-remote="true"` attribute which I'm submitting to a controller in rails.

What I'd like to do is to use the [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) [event system](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) to append data to the request before it gets sent to the server.

Something like this:

```
$("#my_form").bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(xhr, settings){
  // serialize some object and append it
});
```

I can't figure out how to actually tag on the data though?

**Edit** This is what the 'xhr' object looks like in the console.

```
f.Event
currentTarget: DOMWindow
data: undefined
exclusive: undefined
handleObj: Object
handler: function N(a){var b,c,d,e,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p=[],q=[],r=f._data(this,"events");if(!(a.liveFired===this||!r||!r.live||a.target.disabled||a.button&&a.type==="click")){a.namespace&&(n=new RegExp("(^|\\.)"+a.namespace.split(".").join("\\.(?:.*\\.)?")+"(\\.|$)")),a.liveFired=this;var s=r.live.slice(0);for(i=0;i<s.length;i++)g=s[i],g.origType.replace(y,"")===a.type?q.push(g.selector):s.splice(i--,1);e=f(a.target).closest(q,a.currentTarget);for(j=0,k=e.length;j<k;j++){m=e[j];for(i=0;i<s.length;i++){g=s[i];if(m.selector===g.selector&&(!n||n.test(g.namespace))&&!m.elem.disabled){h=m.elem,d=null;if(g.preType==="mouseenter"||g.preType==="mouseleave")a.type=g.preType,d=f(a.relatedTarget).closest(g.selector)[0],d&&f.contains(h,d)&&(d=h);(!d||d!==h)&&p.push({elem:h,handleObj:g,level:m.level})}}}for(j=0,k=p.length;j<k;j++){e=p[j];if(c&&e.level>c)break;a.currentTarget=e.elem,a.data=e.handleObj.data,a.handleObj=e.handleObj,o=e.handleObj.origHandler.apply(e.elem,arguments);if(o===!1||a.isPropagationStopped()){c=e.level,o===!1&&(b=!1);if(a.isImmediatePropagationStopped())break}}return b}}
jQuery16103879226385615766: true
liveFired: HTMLDocument
namespace: ""
namespace_re: /(^|\.)(\.|$)/
result: undefined
target: HTMLFormElement
timeStamp: 1306788242911
type: "ajax:beforeSend"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: what jQuery version are you working with?

Comment: looks like your POST is empty

Comment: It should be in `data` right? The form works perfectly though and I can see that the data is sent (via XMLHttpRequest) in the network tab of dev tools. I don't get it.

Comment: have you tried setting 'data' to something, ex: "foo=bar" and checking to see if it gets submitted

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I set `xhr.data = 'foo'` and then logged the request paramaters on the server. It's not listed. It didn't seem to affect the rest of the request parameters either. Is that definitely the jqXHR object I have a hold of?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I figured this one out myself in the end. It appears that despite what the [docs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax) say, the `ajax:beforeSend` hook actually takes three arguments. According to [this helpful blog post](http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-3-remote-links-and-forms/) they are `event`, `xhr` and `settings`in that order.

The form data I was looking for is in the in the `data` attribute of the `settings` argument.

So basically, I can now add data to the request with the function

```
$("#my_form").bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(event, xhr, settings){
  settings.data += "&serialized=data";
});
```

And the extra paramaters will be available on the server.

Comment: In Firebug I see `null&url=http://www.google.com` but at server side I don't see that `Parameters: {"user_id"=>"13"} `

Comment: @lulalala I am also seeing the same thing. when i **console.log(settings)** i see that **data: "null&customize=TEST"** and the customize param does not persist. I am using **.on("ajax:beforeSend", "#link", function(e,xhr,settings){ settings.data += "&customize=TEST" }**

Comment: Null is default value if not data added, you can write `settings.data = "serialized=data"` but probably it will not work. Use `settings.url += '&dog=cat'` instead.

Comment: This is probably different now since this is old, but the docs do actually reference that with jQuery the first argument will be event object. https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax#important

Answer (score 1):

As of the jQuery 1.5, there is a local **beforeSend** callback that can be bound to your request.  [Documentation link](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events) and another [documentation link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**EDIT:** The request data is available in the *jqXHR* object, the first parameter *beforeSend* callback.

```
beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)
```

Try inspecting the jqXHR object in firebug to see exactly where it stores the POST data and just append your values,

Comment: Ok, I have that in my question (in a roundabout way necessitated by the fact that I'm using Ruby on Rails), but how do I actually append the data to the request?

Comment: I added a log of the XHR object. As you can see the `data` attribute is `undefined`. Have I got the right object?

Answer (score 1):

To change `data` attribute (at least now, using Jquery 1.7.2) inside the `beforeSend` method (the Jquery native method), you can just alter the `this.data` variable.