# How to add an object to jQuery ajax beforeSend's settings.data

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ujs

I'm binding to the beforeSend's ajax form submission:

My function looks like:

```
submitStuff : function(e, xhr, settings) {

    settings.data = {
            invitation : {
                emails : me.returnsArrayX(),
                bucket2 : me.returnsArrayY(),
                bucket3 : me.returnsArrayZ()
            }
    }

}
```

This was working when I was manually submitting to the server like so:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/myurl',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            invitation : {
                emails : me.returnsArrayX(),
                bucket2 : me.returnsArrayY(),
                bucket3 : me.returnsArrayZ()
            }
        }
    });
```

But since I'm using Rails UJS, I would like to use the built in form submitter (data-remote). why would settings.data not work in the above? Do I need to convert the object to an array or something else?

Thanks

Comment: It appears I also need to append data, not replace to not lose the CSRF token

Comment: Where is this `me` variable defined? In the first code snippet is that supposed to be `e`? I'm not familiar with Rails UJS, but the normal signature for the `beforeSend` callback is `(jqXHR, settings)`. If I understand you correctly, you're saying that you're using `submitStuff` as a `beforeSend` callback -- are you or Rails UJS doing something to adjust that to have the extra argument?

Answer (score 3):

Set `processData` to `false`, then you can simply work with an object in the `beforeSend`:

```
$.ajax("/", {
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        settings.data.key2 = "value2";
        settings.data.key3 = {
             more: "values",
             like: "this"
        }; 

        //Encode at end
        settings.data = jQuery.param(settings.data, false);
    },
    data: {
        key: "value"
    },
    processData: false,
    type: "POST"
}​);​
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
submitStuff : function(e, xhr, settings) {

  settings.data += "&serialized=data";

}
```

similar post: [How do I append data to a jquery-ujs post request in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180454/how-do-i-append-data-to-a-jquery-ujs-post-request-in-rails)

Answer (score 1):

For serializing the data I would use [jQuery.param(obj)](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/). So from pdpMathi's example it would look something like this.

```
submitStuff : function(e, xhr, settings) {

    data = {
            invitation : {
                emails : me.returnsArrayX(),
                bucket2 : me.returnsArrayY(),
                bucket3 : me.returnsArrayZ()
            }
    }
    settings.data += "&serialized=" + jQuery.param(data)

}
```

You can see what the above does with some simple example data here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cDdn6/). This allows you to work with your data easily and only serialize it when done.